# Java client server application, can't send an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I searched the internet and i didn't find something for my question.
I have my client class, my server class and a Loc class. In my client class, i have a Jtext field, that i want to populate with values (free/occupied) depending if the seat is free or not.

In my server class i populate an ArrayList with all the seats free. I want to pass this ArrayList to my client and in the same time to display something like FREE FREE OCCUPIED.
But i can only pass my first value.
Here is the server class:

```
public static void main(String [] args){

ServerSocket client = null;
Loc l = new Loc();

    try {
         ArrayList<Loc> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            l.setLoc(i);
            l.setRand(j);
            lista.add(l);
        }
        client = new ServerSocket(9000);
        Socket socket = client.accept();
        ObjectInputStream dis = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        l = (Loc) dis.readObject();
        System.out.println(l.getRand());
       // Loc a = new Loc("ags",2, 42, 125);

        dos.writeObject(lista);


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

And here is my client class:

```
public class Client_Gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Socket socket = null;
ObjectOutputStream dos = null;
ObjectInputStream dis= null;
// ObjectOutputStream dos = null;
ArrayList<Loc> lst  = new ArrayList<>();
Loc locul = new Loc();
/**
 * Creates new form Client_Gui
 */
public Client_Gui() {
    initComponents();

    Loc  loc = new Loc();
    try {
        ArrayList<Loc> lst = null;
        socket = new Socket("localhost",9000);           
        dos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dis = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dos.writeObject(loc);
        lst = (ArrayList<Loc>) dis.readObject();
        for(Loc a : lst){
           if(a.getIdSpectator().equals("") == true)
                        txt_area.setText("Liber");
                     else 
                       txt_area.setText("Ocupat");
       }



    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client_Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client_Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

And another question related to this. Can i run my client/server application without sending first some information from the client? I mean, at first i tried to read from client first and then write to server but i got errors. After i changed, and first i write from client and then read, works normally, until it reaches that part with ArrayList.

EDIT: i tried to hard code and in my Client class i put the array list created by code.
Now, when i want to show it in the text field, still only the first value is displayed. Is my syntax wrong?
i used:

```
          for(Loc a : lista){
           if(a.getIdSpectator().equals("") == true)
                        txt_area.setText("Liber");                            
                     else 
                       txt_area.setText("Ocupat ");
            }
```

EDIT2: Jasper was right. I used append and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Does `Loc` implement the `Serializable` interface?

Comment: Yes. It does implements Serializable.

Comment: I think you should use `txt_area.append("Liber\n");` for what you are trying to do. `setText` will overwrite what's already in the text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how you are constructing the list on the server....

```
ArrayList<Loc> lista = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
        l.setLoc(i);
        l.setRand(j);
        lista.add(l);
    }
```

Basically, all this is doing is adding the same instance of `l` to the array list, but on each loop, you are changing its properties. This means, you'll end up with a list of the same object with the same properties (cause it's just the single instance of the object)

What you should be doing is on each iteration of your loop is creating a new instance of what ever `l` is, setting its properties according only and that to the list

**Updated**

Okay, on client, you're setting the text of the `JTextArea` using

```
for(Loc a : lst){
    if(a.getIdSpectator().equals("") == true)
        txt_area.setText("Liber");
    else 
        txt_area.setText("Ocupat");
}
```

`setText` replaces the contents of the field with the supplied text.  Instead, you want to try using `append`

```
for(Loc a : lst){
    if(a.getIdSpectator().equals("") == true)
        txt_area.append("Liber");
    else 
        txt_area.append("Ocupat");
}
```

Having said that, I would highly recommend that you consider taking a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for components that are better suited to display this type of data

Comment: I thought of that after i posted and i turned it to:

 `for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
            {
                Loc l = new Loc();
                l.setLoc(i);
                l.setRand(j);
                lista.add(l);
            }`

Sorry, i don't know how to format the code right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in a `loop` so all of your values passed from the socket will be recieve by the server not just the first value you send.

**example:**

in server

```
ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

dos.writeObject(lista);

while(true)
{
    l = (Loc) dis.readObject();
    System.out.println(l.getRand());
   // Loc a = new Loc("ags",2, 42, 125);
}
```

in client

```
    dis = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    lst = (ArrayList<Loc>) dis.readObject();
    for(Loc a : lst){
       if(a.getIdSpectator().equals("") == true)
                    txt_area.setText("Liber");
                 else 
                   txt_area.setText("Ocupat");
   }
```

your question:

```
Can i run my client/server application without sending first some information from the client?
```

just always remember when you are trying to read data packet, someone should write data first.

Comment: I understand the answer for the second question, but for the first i still don't get it.I read only one value because my program doesn't work if i skip this part. I don't really need to read that object. In my server i have an ArrayList and i have to pass all the values to the client. When i want to show on my form the data, all i get is the data from the first object in my ArrayList. That's my problem. I tried what you suggested and it didn't work. Thanks for the fast answer.